# How to change a negative value to a positive number not exceeding 49

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Hi I have the following question that I am struggling with solving

I have si numbers from a lotto draw to which firstly I would like to subtract each number by 25 and record into cells , therafter if the result is a negative number I would like to add a formula to add 49 to the negative number to get to a positive number ex
 6 27 15 26 33 7  6-25= -19 this wil be added to cell h2 this negative number  should be added to cell l2 after adding 49 if the number is negative.

```
b2=6 c2=27 d2=15 e2=26 f2=33 g2 =7
h2 = -19( 6-25) i2 =2 (27-25) etc
n2 = h2 if negative 49 to be added to make it a positive number
... s2
```

I will greatly appreciate help with a formula please for excel
also if value in the first is 25 so 25-25 = 0 if zero 49 to be added

Thank you in anticipation for all the help received

Comment: First step: In a cell, let's say, beneath the b2 cell, enter the "=" sign. Then a popup of choices will come down. That's where you want to start. Write it down, in steps, what you want logically. That's it. It will be too easy if you just write it down first in words. When you get stuck, come back and edit your question and show your work. I'll be happy to help out. Hint: "IF"

Answer (score 1):

Use one formula -- no need for multiple cells.

```
=IF(B2<=25,B2+24,B2-25)
```

This first checks whether subtracting 25 will result in a negative number or zero. If it will, do the same as you would subtracting 25 and then adding 49 -- this is a net result of adding 24 to the number. Otherwise, i.e., if the number is greater than 25, subtract 25.